# How to make multi worded boot name for GRUB

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub

When doing grub-install with —-bootloader-id, it only takes the first word, but I want to make a multi worded boot option. Is this even possible and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the option, like `--bootloader-id="Linux Boot Loader"`? Or maybe escaping the spaces, like `--bootloader-id=Linux\ Boot\ Loader`?

Comment: Just about everywhere in Linux, you have to quote or escape spaces. I just use CamelCase, under_line, or justonename and stopped using spaces.